# NioSocketChannel$WriteRequestQueue causing OutOfMemory

Tags: java, netty

I am using **Netty** to perform large **file upload**. It works fine but the RAM used by the client seems to increase with the size of the file. This is not the expected behaviour since everything is piped from the Reading the source file to writing the target file.

At first, I thought about a kind of adaptive buffer growing up until Xmx is reached but **setting Xmx to a reasonable value (50M) would lead to an OutOfMemoryError** soon after starting upload.
After some research using Eclipse Memory Analyzer, it appears that the object retaining the heap memory is:

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel$WriteRequestQueue
```

Is there any option for setting a limit to this queue or do I have to code my own queue using ChannelFutures to control the number of bytes and block the pipe when the limit is reached?

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Renaud

Comment: Or you could increase the maximum memory. 1 GB isn't much these days.

Comment: Not an option for a Desktop background application. Though it is quite a pain not to be able to transfert a file without using 1GB or RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from @normanmaurer on Netty Github

You should use

```
Channel.isWritable()
```

to check if the "queue" is full. If so you will need to check if there is enough space to write more. So the effect you see can happen if you write data to quickly to get it send out to the clients.
You can get around this kind of problems when try to write a File via DefaultFileRegion or ChunkedFile.

---

@normanmaurer thank you I missed this method of the Channel!
I guess I need to read what's happening inside:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler
```

---

UPDATED: 2012/08/30
This is the code I made to solve my problem:

```
public class LimitedChannelSpeaker{
    Channel channel;
    final Object lock = new Object();
    long maxMemorySizeB;
    long size = 0;
    Map<ChannelBufferRef, Integer> buffer2readablebytes = new HashMap<ChannelBufferRef, Integer>();

    public LimitedChannelSpeaker(Channel channel, long maxMemorySizeB) {
        this.channel= channel;
        this.maxMemorySizeB = maxMemorySizeB;
    }

    public ChannelFuture speak(ChannelBuffer buff) {
        if (buff.readableBytes() > maxMemorySizeB) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The buffer is larger than the maximum allowed size of " + maxMemorySizeB + "B.");
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (size + buff.readableBytes() > maxMemorySizeB) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
            ChannelBufferRef ref = new ChannelBufferRef(buff);
            ref.register();
            ChannelFuture future = channel.write(buff);
            future.addListener(new ChannelBufferRef(buff));
            return future;
        }
    }

    private void spoken(ChannelBufferRef ref) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ref.unregister();
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    private class ChannelBufferRef implements ChannelFutureListener {

        int readableBytes;

        public ChannelBufferRef(ChannelBuffer buff) {
            readableBytes = buff.readableBytes();
        }

        public void unregister() {
            buffer2readablebytes.remove(this);
            size -= readableBytes;
        }

        public void register() {
            buffer2readablebytes.put(this, readableBytes);
            size += readableBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
            spoken(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> for a Desktop background application

Netty is designed for highly scalable servers e.g. around 10,000 connections. For a desktop application with less than a few hundred connections, I would use plain IO. You may find the code is much simpler and it should use less than 1 MB.

Comment: The code is already there, and we will not rollback to a plain IO implementation. A lot cheaper to implement a queue where each item written to the channel when added to the queue and removed from the queue when the WriteFuture is done.

Comment: That may be your best option. Netty is still going to use more memory that a plain IO solution but at least it will be more bounded.

Comment: I don't agree about memory consumption with Netty, the client bootstrap is not memory-consuming and the nio approach with a worker thread will quickly allow to save some threads when performing parallel networking tasks.

Comment: @NumRenaud it will save some threads, but if you have a desktop application running on a machine with limited resources, how many connections are you using? For the smallest memory footprint with a small number of connections using simple blocking code will be more light weight.

Comment: I agree with you, but my question is "How do you put a limit to the WriteQueue in netty". I cannot believe that this functionality is not implemented in the API!

Comment: It doesn't surprise me as you don't appear to be using netty for what it was designed for.

Comment: Okay what if I need 10 people to be able to download 1Gb files in parallel from the server? Do I need 10Gb of RAM on the server for this? It doesn't seems reasonable to me. In no situation should the write queue keep increasing for ever, it should block at some level, at least befor Xmx is reached!

Comment: Potentially, if you writes are getting ahead of your consumers. Netty is designed to be non-blocking, or potentially close the connection.

Comment: @NumRenaud in the next major version of netty you will be able to specify the queue implementation that you want to use. So you could just use a boundet queue here

Comment: @NormanMaurer Thank you Norman, you should copy paste my answer with your name to be rewarded instead of me!